# CSS is it possible to use element after :hover?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use element after hover effect

I tried like this

```
.tableclass tr td:hover a{
   color:#fff;
}
```

what i am trying to do that when i hover the td so then anchor link inside that td should change its color to white..

here is how i tried my self but not working for me?

```
.GridAlternate td:hover a , .GridRowStyle td:hover a{
    color:#fff;
}
```

My GridView HTML

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;" id="GV_Users" rules="rows" class="DefaultGridStyle">
                        <tbody><tr class="GridHeader">
                            <th scope="col">User Name</th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$CPH_Content$TC_SysUsers$TP_Users$GV_Users','Sort$RoleName')">Role Name</a></th><th valign="middle" align="left" style="width:22%;" scope="col">LogIn</th><th valign="middle" align="center" style="width:33%;" scope="col">Action</th>
                        </tr><tr class="GridRowStyle">
                            <td>
                                Ali Nisarr
                            </td><td>
                                Admin
                            </td><td valign="middle" align="left">
                                alinisar@ken.com
                            </td><td valign="middle" align="center">
                                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$CPH_Content$TC_SysUsers$TP_Users$GV_Users$ctl02$Lbtn_change','')" class="editlinkbutton" id="Lbtn_change">Edit</a>
                                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$CPH_Content$TC_SysUsers$TP_Users$GV_Users$ctl02$Lbtn_Remove','')" class="removelinkbutton" id="Lbtn_Remove">Remove</a>

                                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$CPH_Content$TC_SysUsers$TP_Users$GV_Users$ctl02$Lbtn_Disable','')" class="removelinkbutton" id="Lbtn_Disable">Disable</a>

                            </td>
                        </tr><tr class="GridAlternate">
                            <td>
                                Nizam Ullah
                            </td><td>
                                Admin
                            </td><td valign="middle" align="left">
                                nizam@ken.com
                            </td><td valign="middle" align="center">
                                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$CPH_Content$TC_SysUsers$TP_Users$GV_Users$ctl03$Lbtn_change','')" class="editlinkbutton" id="Lbtn_change">Edit</a>
                                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$CPH_Content$TC_SysUsers$TP_Users$GV_Users$ctl03$Lbtn_Remove','')" class="removelinkbutton" id="Lbtn_Remove">Remove</a>

                                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$CPH_Content$TC_SysUsers$TP_Users$GV_Users$ctl03$Lbtn_Disable','')" class="removelinkbutton" id="Lbtn_Disable">Disable</a>

                            </td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                        <table class="GridPager">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td width="7%">
                                    Showing 
                                    :
                                </td>
                                <td width="5%">
                                    <span id="lbl_rowstartindex">1</span>
                                    &nbsp;-
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="lbl_rowendindex">2</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    of
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="lbl_totalrecords">2</span>
                                </td>

                                <td width="50%" align="center">

                                    &nbsp;

                                    &nbsp;

                                    &nbsp;

                                    &nbsp;

                                    &nbsp;

                                    &nbsp;

                                </td>
                                <td width="18%" align="right">
                                    Displaying per page:
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <input type="text" id="TxBx_PageSize" maxlength="3" value="10" name="ctl00$CPH_Content$TC_SysUsers$TP_Users$GV_Users$ctl05$TxBx_PageSize">

                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$CPH_Content$TC_SysUsers$TP_Users$GV_Users$ctl05$lb_Change_RowsPerChange','')" id="lb_Change_RowsPerChange">Change</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
```

Am i doing something wrong or is there any other approach i should follow?

Comment: Yes i tried but may be i think i am doing something wrong?

Comment: Put an example into fiddle to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @EdHeal
Done.. added my css code..

Comment: @EdHeal fiddle seems to be down for now

Comment: Post your HTML as well

Comment: seems to be working here http://plnkr.co/edit/qAPnabHNp1KH1RXgaUu2?p=preview

Comment: A big "YES" to you my dear friend. I use it all the time.

Comment: @Blender
Thanyou 4 interest Added the HTML code too..

Comment: @ArunPJohny
Many Thanks for link, and i was thinking it is not possible..
But why it is not working for ME?

Comment: @SyedHaiderHassan seems fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/qAPnabHNp1KH1RXgaUu2?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this;

```
tr.GridAlternate td:hover a , tr.GridRowStyle td:hover a{
    color:#fff;
}
```

And make sure to insert this at the end of the style sheet. **Maybe it is being override by other class**.
I hope this helps

Comment: yes it was being overrided by anchor tag it self..

I mean
a
{
    color: #660000;
}

was defined after my css..

Answer (score 2):

http://codepen.io/princemaple/pen/Dcxdi

It's totally working for me.
I assume some of your rules are wrongly cascaded?
Like you have more specific targeting rules overrides this rule...

Comment: Yes it was being overrided by other class.. 
My mistake.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try 
    .tableclass td:hover a { 
                    color:#fff;
                 }

Comment: I already did that but with it the color only changes when i hover over the anchor tag.

What i want is that when i hover the td element of table then inside that td all the anchor tags change its color.

Comment: @user1590011 that'll not change the `<a>` color.

Comment: it only changes the normal text color

Comment: Oh I got your question, the selector you have written in question is fine, i just tested it and it should work.